# Confidence interval regression issue with quantile data

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, quantile-regression

I am trying to tie out the confidence intervals of the 124.88 intercept on page  8 here:

http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~roger/research/rq/vig.pdf

Here is the code:

```
#here you can see the 124.88 number

library(quantreg)
data(engel)
engel
data.frame(percentile = c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95), coef = cbind( coef( rq(foodexp~income,tau=c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95))  )[1,] )  )


        percentile      coef
tau= 0.05       0.05 124.88004
tau= 0.25       0.25  95.48354
tau= 0.50       0.50  81.48225
tau= 0.75       0.75  62.39659
tau= 0.95       0.95  64.10396
```

Now I want to calculate the confidence interval for the tau = .05

```
coef( rq(foodexp~income,tau=c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95)))[1,1] + coef(summary( rq(foodexp~income,tau=c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95)),se="nid")[[1]]  )[,"Std. Error"][1]*1.96
```

I get an upper CI of

```
(Intercept) 
   193.6108
```

Hows is the author showing 130.517?

ALSO - on page 8 the intercept plot has an axis range from 400 to 800 but 95th percentile is 64 and lower than the 5th percentile NOT higher.  Hows that plot make any sense?

Comment: Maybe he used some other method?

Comment: I tried se = boot, ker and nid and none of them match